# Terminal not showing any output?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, root-access

I have succesfully root and unroot my device but my terminal doesn't show any output only error messages of missing command.

I'm also unable to re-root my device. I copied `psneuter` to `/data/local/tmp` but the terminal doesn't give an error.

I have verified it by createing  a file in `/data/local/tmp` and copied it to my sdcard. The file doesn't exist. Gingerbreak doesn't work and gives an error `Couldn't extract asset`.

I have an orphaned su on my device but it has only user rights. Is there a way I can fix my terminal and re-root my device?

Comment: You may want to mention what device you're having problems with.

Comment: @onik:I used a modified boot.img and psneuter or zergrush. My device is a Pioneer Gionnee 100